# RxSwift call a method on error event or don't call it at all

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I have the following issue. I have two methods that both return `Single<String>`. I want to call the first at the beginning (e.g. user action) and if I get a `.success` event, I want to initialize navigation. However, when an error occurs, I first want to call another method and do display and after that display an error or do the navigation depending on its result.

The concrete example:

- I start a view controller and trigger a login function.
- If the silent login fails to get a token (gets an error event), I want to have a login mask (an interactive token request) shown to the user.
- If the silent login works, I don't want to show the login mask and just start the navigation.

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa

final class SignInViewModel {
    private let authService: AuthenticationService
    private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    
    let loadingErrorOccurred = PublishSubject<Void>()
    
    init(authService: AuthenticationService) {
        self.authService = authService
    }
    
    func signInUser(in viewController: UIViewController) {
        // I want to trigger the getTokenInteractively when the getTokenSilently() fails
        // and never trigger it if it succeeds.

        getTokenSilently()
            .asObservable()
            .take(1)
            .catchAndReturn("")
            .map { token in !token.isEmpty }
            .bind(to: wasSilentTokenRequestSuccessful)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
    
    private func getTokenSilently() -> Single<String> {
        return Single.create { [authService] observer -> Disposable in
            authService.getTokenSilently { token, error in
                if let token = token, error != nil {
                    observer(.success(token))
                } else {
                    observer(.failure(error ?? UnknownError()))
                }
            }
            
            return Disposables.create()
        }
    }
    
    private func getTokenInteractively(viewController: UIViewController) -> Single<String> {
        return Single.create { [authService] observer -> Disposable in
            authService.getTokenInteractively(parentView: viewController) { token, error in
                if let token = token, error != nil {
                    observer(.success(token))
                } else {
                    observer(.failure(error ?? UnknownError()))
                }
            }
            
            return Disposables.create()
        }
    }
}
```

I'm looking for a proper way of achieving the desired result. I thought of some kind of operator that first triggers one function, and only if the result of that fails it will trigger the next function. The rest of the stream could then stay the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A useful operator to know in this context is `catchError()` which will allow you to replace an error event with some other observable.

First, I suggest you move your two network calls into the authentication service where they belong.

```
extension AuthenticationService {
    func rx_getTokenSilently() -> Single<String> {
        Single.create { observer in
            getTokenSilently { (result, error) in
                if let result = result {
                    observer(.success(result))
                }
                else {
                    observer(.error(error ?? RxError.unknown))
                }
            }
            return Disposables.create()
        }
    }

    func rx_getTokenInteractively(parentView: UIViewController) -> Single<String> {
        Single.create { observer in
            getTokenInteractively(parentView: parentView) { (result, error) in
                if let result = result {
                    observer(.success(result))
                }
                else {
                    observer(.error(error ?? RxError.unknown))
                }
            }
            return Disposables.create()
        }
    }
}
```

Now your SignInViewModel can look something like this:

```
final class SignInViewModel {
    private let authService: AuthenticationService
    private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    private let _token = PublishSubject<String>()
    private let _loadingErrorOccurred = PublishSubject<Error>()

    // your view controller can subscribe to these two in order to do its navigation.
    let token: Observable<String>
    let loadingErrorOccurred: Observable<Error>

    init(authService: AuthenticationService) {
        self.authService = authService
        token = _token.asObservable()
        loadingErrorOccurred = _loadingErrorOccurred.asObservable()
    }

    func signInUser(in viewController: UIViewController) {
        let tokenResult = authService.rx_getTokenSilently() // make first request
            .catchError { [authService] _ in
                // if first request fails, make second request
                authService.rx_getTokenInteractively(parentView: viewController)
            }
            .asObservable()
            .materialize()

        tokenResult.compactMap { $0.element } // if the either request succeeds
        .bind(to: _token) // notify the VC of the token
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)

        tokenResult
            .compactMap { $0.error } // if both requests fail
            .bind(to: _loadingErrorOccurred) // notify the VC of the error
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
}
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for! One question left, in the `authService` where you return the `Single` you have this code: `observer(.error(error ?? RxError.unknown))`. However, for me, I can only use `.success` and `.failure`. Is there a difference between failure and error?

Comment: I also would like to make one addition. For the second `tokenResult` binding, I've added a `.skip(1)` after the `compactMap`. I only wanted to display an error message when both attempts fail.

Comment: What version of RxSwift are you using? My SingleEvent enum has success and error, not success and failure. I expect they are the same.

Comment: I use version 6.0.0